# 429 Too Many Requests when user login

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom

When checking the locale storage, if there is a token, the user should be redirected to the "movies" page, protected by the protector route.

Component  - App/js

```
const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = React.useState(false);
const tokenCheck = () => {
    const jwt = localStorage.getItem('jwt');
    if (!jwt) {
        return
    }

    mainApi.getContent(jwt)
        .then((res) => {
            if (res) {
                setLoggedIn(true);
                history.push('/movies')
            }
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            setIsOpenPopup(true);
            setPopupTitle('error tokenCheck');
        });
};

React.useEffect(() => {
    tokenCheck();
}, [tokenCheck]);
```

But it doesn't happen, the request loops.
Main body

```
return (
    <CurrentUserContext.Provider value={currentUser}>
            <main>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path="/signin">
                        () =>
                             !loggedIn ? <Login onLogin={onLogin} /> : <Redirect to="/movies" />
                        }
                    </Route>

                    <ProtectedRoute path="/movies"><Movies/></ProtectedRoute>
                </Switch>
            </main>
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
    </CurrentUserContext.Provider>
```

component api, request to api

```
class MainApi {
    constructor(options) {
        this._baseUrl = options.baseUrl;
    }

 getContent = (jwt) => {
    return fetch(`${this._baseUrl}/users/me`, {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${jwt}`,
        },
    })
        .then(this._returnResult);
};
```

I get error "429 Too Many Requests "

Answer (score 0):

`tokenCheck` is redeclared each render cycle, so it will ***always*** invoke the `useEffect` hook callback.

You can either move `tokenCheck` declaration *into* the `useEffect` hook so it is not an external dependency:

```
const jwt = localStorage.getItem('jwt');

React.useEffect(() => {
  const tokenCheck = (jwt) => {
    mainApi.getContent(jwt)
      .then((res) => {
        if (res) {
          setLoggedIn(true);
          history.push('/movies')
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        setIsOpenPopup(true);
        setPopupTitle('error tokenCheck');
      });
  };

  if (jwt) {
    tokenCheck(jwt);
  }
}, [jwt]);
```

Or memoize the `tokenCheck` callback.

```
const jwt = localStorage.getItem('jwt');

const tokenCheck = useCallback((jwt) => {
  mainApi.getContent(jwt)
    .then((res) => {
      if (res) {
        setLoggedIn(true);
        history.push('/movies')
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      setIsOpenPopup(true);
      setPopupTitle('error tokenCheck');
    });
}, []);

React.useEffect(() => {
  if (jwt) {
    tokenCheck(jwt);
  }
}, [jwt, tokenCheck]);
```